# Need an Ajax call to destroy session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, event-listener

I have a script where when a user get verified he/she is brought to `Home.php`. At the moment `Home.php` doesn't do much. But in the bottom left hand corner I have a log out button. And as you know when the user clicks on this button he expects his session to be destroyed and for him to be redirected to a log in page. Unfortunately you can't make a click listener in `php`. I have browsed for an hour looking for a solution but I have not been able to find the right key word or something.
This is my code

EDIT: You only really have to read some code from `Home.php` the est is only if someoe wants to run the code if they are not sure of their answer

`Index.php`(Login Page)

```
<?php

session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cannot");
mysql_select_db("virtualdiary") or die ("db");

if (isset ($_POST["Username"])&& isset($_POST["Password"]))
{


$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

$_SESSION["username"] = $Username;

$DB_Check = " SELECT * from users Where username = '".$Username."' and password = '".$Password."' " ;
$result = mysql_query($DB_Check);

if(mysql_fetch_assoc($result) === false){
    $error = "invalid username or password";
    }else{
    header( 'Location: Home.php' ) ;

    }
     }
?>

 <html>

<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css"/>
<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="messages">
 <?php 
 if(isset($error))
  echo $error; ?>
</div>
<form action="Index.php" method="post">
 <h5>Diary Name:</h5>
     <input name="Username" type="text"/>

 <h5>Password:</h5>
     <input name="Password" type="password"/>
     </br>
     </br>
     </br>

     <input name="login" type="submit"/>

 </form>

 <p>Click <a href="Register.php">HERE </a>to register.</p>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`Home.php`

```
  <?php 
session_start();
echo "Username = " . $_SESSION["username"] . " !";

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cannot");
mysql_select_db("virtualdiary") or die ("db");

if (isset($_POST["entry"])){



$entry = $_POST["entry"];

$submission = "INSERT INTO `virtualdiary`.`entries` (`entry`) VALUES ('". $entry . "')";

mysql_query($submission);
}
 ?>

 <html>

 <head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css"/>
 <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Entry:  </h1>
 <form method="post" action="Home.php">
    <textarea name="entry" rows="24" cols="87">
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["entry"])){
    echo $entry;
   } 
?>
</textarea>
     </br>
 </br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit"/>     
   </form>

     <button id="LogOut"><a href="Index.php">Log Out</a></button>
     </body>

   </html>
```

From what I have found from searching around I will need a `Home.js` file with an ajax call. I don't know the first thing about Ajax so I will probably need code to paste or a very blunt tutorial. 
                                                      Thanks

Comment: How css code can be related to ajax and sessions?

Comment: Could you not just do <a href="Index.php?logout"> and then at the top of index.php use: if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { session_destroy(); } - No need for ajax. The user will then be shown the login form.

Comment: `<button id="LogOut" onclick="jsfunction()">Log Out</button>` Then make jsfunction() log the user out and redirect the user via Ajax.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: tks @Quentin I only need it present so I didn't get bogged down with seurity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the logout href to /Logout.php, and in Logout.php have

```php
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: /Index.php');
?>
```

That will simply destroy the users current session, then redirect the user back to the Index.php page.

The AJAX way would be (using jQuery, I can't remember the vanilla JS syntax for ajax calls)

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Logout.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'loggedOut') {
            window.location.href = 'Index.php';
        }
    }
});
```

And then you'd need to change Logout.php, instead of the header line, make it echo/die/print `loggedOut` (or a json string which would probably be better, but this is just an example).

Comment: thanks I was looking for something like that all morning

Comment: No problem, don't forget it an answer helps you to upvote it, and accept it if it solved your problem.